# If $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2[0,1]$, then $F_n\to F$ uniformly where $F_n=\int_{0}^{x}f_n$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrCh7.png]

This is the full problem. a) Is easy. However, I  feel I solved b) not in an intended way so I would want to get a check on my work and perhaps some different solutions.

b) This is simply weak convergence and so the sequence $f_n$ is bounded in $L^2$. We also have pointwise convergence by weak convergence. Now I claim $F_n$ are equicontinuous. $|\int_{y}^{x}f_n|\leq\|f_n\|_2|x-y|\leq M|x-y|$ Where $M$ is the bound on $f_n$. $[0,1]$ is compact so equicontinuity + pointwise  implies uniform.

Comment: Your argument looks good to me, and my hunch is that it cannot be simplified.  You are proving that the operator $T : L^2[0,1] \to C([0,1])$ defined by $Tf(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is [completely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Completely_continuous_operators).  Since $L^2$ is a Hilbert space, this is equivalent to $T$ being a compact operator, and anything to do with compactness in $C([0,1])$ almost inevitably involves equicontinuity.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah! It is an compact operator so it maps weak convergent to strong convergent! I did not even look at it that way! Thank you Nate!